# Reading data from ods(Open office spreadsheet) for selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium

Is there any possibility of using ods(Open office spreadsheet) files for read and write data in selenium using java. I searched internet and i am not find any way. Pls anyone help me.

Comment: Can't you save your data in `.xls` file?

Comment: yes. My company have only open office

Comment: Open office supports saving and loading from `.xls` extension.

Comment: ok. thanks for your information

Comment: And then, you can use `jxl` library to operate on `.xls` files

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("file location");
Sheet sheet = SpreadSheet.createFromFile(file).getSheet(0)MutableCell domain = null;
sheet.getCellAt(row index,column index).setValue(value you want to write in the cell) / getvalue()-fetches the value in the cell;
sheet.getSpreadSheet().saveAs(file);
```

**Note**: 
For using this, you need `openjdocument` jar file added to your project.

Answer (score 0):

First import library

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.miachm.sods</groupId>
        <artifactId>SODS</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

then this is an example on how to read the first column

```
public static List<String> readColumnA(String filePath) {
    List<String> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        SpreadSheet spread = new SpreadSheet(new File(filePath));
        //     System.out.println("Number of sheets: " + spread.getNumSheets());
        Sheet sheet = spread.getSheets().get(0);
        //     System.out.println("In sheet " + sheet.getName());
        Range movies = sheet.getDataRange();
        Object[][] movieColumn = movies.getValues();
        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getMaxRows(); i++) {
            movieList.add(movieColumn[i][0].toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return movieList;
}
```